# MSTest ExpectedException Test Failing

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, mstest, entity-framework-4.3

So, I'm confused by this failure.  I'm using MSTest to run some integration tests (since there's a DB backing this, I guess we'd call it that rather than unit testing) and have a test method like so:

```
[TestMethod()]
[ExpectedException(typeof(DbUpdateException))]
public void AddRecipe_InvalidCookingMethod_ExpectExceptionThrown()
{
   var target = GetRepository();
   var recipe = new Recipe()
   {
      Method = "Sous-vide"
   }
   target.AddRecipe(recipe);
}
```

and the `AddRecipe` looks like this:

```
public void AddRecipe(Recipe recipe)
{
   // validation stuff
   // automapper stuff
   try
   {
      using (var context = GetContext())
      {
         context.recipes.Add(recipe);
         context.SaveChanges();
      }
   }
   catch (DbUpdateException ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
      throw;
   }
}
```

The underlying table has a foreign key to the `cooking_method` table and in this case the recipe I'm trying to insert has a cooking method that isn't in that table, so I expect a **DbUpdateException** to be thrown.

The test fails and states "AddRecipe_InvalidCookingMethod_ExpectExceptionThrown threw exception System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException, but exception System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was expected...."  It goes on to mention that there's an inner exception of type **MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException**: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails..."

I'm using the MySql connector 6.4.4, entity framework 4.3, VS 2010, if any of that is useful info.

Ideas?

---

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to Ladislav for helping out with this one.  I'd moved the source tree and updated *most* but not all of the references.  My test project was referencing the wrong version of Entity Framework.

Comment: Can you validate that both your test project and tested project use the same EF library?

Comment: That was it - moved the code and one was referencing the wrong one.  Thanks!  If you make that an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed in comment this looks like a problem where projects in solution use different version of EntityFramework.dll library.